# Installing packages on a x86-64 linux

Tags: linux, centos, yum, x86-64

I have CentoOS 5.4 x86-64 and every time I do `yum install ...` two versions of the same package are installed: one ending in `.i386` and the other ending in `.x86_64`.

Is it nessesary to install `.i386` versions given my OS is x86_64?
Have I just been wasting space by always installing both `.i386` and `.x86_64` versions of the same package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this [forum](http://forum.slicehost.com/comments.php?DiscussionID=2274), It seems you need to exclude some specific architectures.

Add this line to your **/etc/yum.conf**:

```
exclude=*.i386 *.i586 *.i686
```

Note that this can have some implications (see forum post).

Comment: So, I guess the answer is No. You dont need to install .i386 packages on a x86-64 linux.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

*However*, if you are using some package(s) that require 32 bit libs/packages then yes, you need them. This is most often seen (as on my workstation) in the requirements for running the Adobe Flash plugin.

This is not normal. Perhaps somewhere along the line you installed some 32 bit packages(s) that are the cause of subsequent 32 bit package installs. Look in the yum install log and see if you can pinpoint the first 32 bit packages installed. Check if there is anything on the system which requires 32 bit support (like the aforementioned flash or windows apps running on wine).